# php- Output directory does not exist

Tags: php, directory, save, file-put-contents

I am trying to save new file to my initial directory in my Symfony project but whatever I tried it throws:

> Output directory does not exist

As I am sure that path exist a want to create a .txt file in it!

```
$path = "/var/www/app/web/uploads/my-file.txt";
$file = basename($path);

$txt = new File();
$txt->setSavePath($file);
$txt->save();
```

and:

```
public function setSavePath($savePath)
{
    if (!is_dir($savePath)) {
        throw \Exception("Output directory does not exist");
    }

    // Add trailing directory separator the save path
    if (substr($savePath, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
        $savePath .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    $this->savePath = $savePath;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure the casing is the same (capital vs lowercase) Linux is case sensitive.  Also make sure the PHP system user has permission to those folders.  They could exist and be owned by root with no permissions for PHP to access them, then he wont see them.

Comment: Shouldn't `setSavePath()` get the full path and not just the filename? Right now, you're just passing the filename (without path, since you used `basename()`). Then, in the method, you're checking if there's a folder with the same name as the file. If there isn't one, you're outputting _"Output directory does not exist"_. I'm quite sure that's not what you meant to do, right?

Comment: Tried! Error is the same. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Did you pass the path only, or did you pass the complete string (including the filename)? Looking at the code, it should _only_ get the path without the filename or you will get the same issue again (since it will check if the filename is a folder).

Comment: obviously the directory does not exist or you made a typo. Echo the results of `$file` and try to see if you can reach that path manually. You could also try `/` vs ` \ `

Comment: A dump() it. Returns "/var/www/appweb/uploads" so that is fine. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) instead [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Because

```
$path = "/var/www/app/web/uploads/my-file.txt";
$file = basename($path);
// $file is `my-file.txt` and not the path `/var/www/app/web/uploads` you expect
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the $savePath is a directory `is_dir`, you are passing a file path, because of that your exception is thrown.

You should check is **$savePath** is a directory and its writable.

```
public function setSavePath($savePath)
{
    if (!is_writable(dirname($savePath))) {
        throw \Exception("Output directory does not exist or not writable.");
    }

   //... rest of code.
}
```

ref: http://php.net/is_dir
ref: http://php.net/is_writable